# Programmaticaly find next state for max(Q(s',a')) in q-learning using R

Tags: r, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am writing a simple grid world q-learning program using R. This is my grid world

[image]

This simple grid world has 6 states in which state 1 and state 6 are starting and ending state. I avoided adding a fire pit, wall, wind so to keep my grid world as simple as possible. For reward matrix I have starting state value-0.1 and ending state a +1 and rest of the state 0. A -0.1 reward for starting state is to discourage the agent from coming back to the start position.

```
#Reward and action-value matrix 
Row=state(1:6)
Column=actions(1:4)[Left,Right,Down,Up in that order]
```

I wrote my program in R and its working but with a problem in finding next state when current state is greater than 4th row. The Q matrix doesn't update after 4th row.

```
#q-learning example
#https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning

# 2x3 grid world
# S for starting grid G for goal/terminal grid
# actions left right down up
#  4 5 6 state
#########
# [0,0,G]
# [S,0,0]
#########
#  1 2 3 state

#setting seed
set.seed(2016)
#number of iterations
N=10
#discount factor
gamma=0.9

#learning rate
alpha=0.1

#target state
tgt.state=6

#reward matrix starting grid has -0.1 and ending grid has 1
R=matrix( c( NA,  0,  NA,  0,
            -0.1, 0,  NA,  0,
             0,  NA,  NA,  1,
             NA,  0,-0.1, NA,
             0,   1,   0, NA, 
             0,   NA,  0, NA
            ),
          nrow=6,ncol=4,byrow = TRUE) 

#initializing Q matrix with zeros
Q=matrix( rep( 0, len=dim(R)[1]*dim(R)[2]), nrow = dim(R)[1],ncol=dim(R)[2])


for (i in 1:N) {
  ## for each episode, choose an initial state at random
  cs <- 1
  ## iterate until we get to the tgt.state
  while (1) {
    ## choose next state from possible actions at current state
    ## Note: if only one possible action, then choose it;
    ## otherwise, choose one at random
    next.states <- which(R[cs,] > -1)
    if (length(next.states)==1)
      ns <- next.states
    else
      ns <- sample(next.states,1)
    ## this is the update
    Q[cs,ns] <- Q[cs,ns] + alpha*(R[cs,ns] + gamma*max(Q[ns, which(R[ns,] > -1)]) - Q[cs,ns])
    ## break out of while loop if target state is reached
    ## otherwise, set next.state as current.state and repeat      
    if (ns == tgt.state) break
    cs <- ns
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    print(Q)
  }
}
```

Currently when my algorithm starts the agent always start from the state-1. In the first state(first row of R) there are two actions either Right(R(1,2)) or Up(R(1,4)). If randomly selected an action say **Up (R(1,4))** then the agent move to next state as the action Q(4,action).

But now consider state-4(forth row or R) it has two action Right-R(4,2) and Down-R(4,3) this cause problem for my algorithm and if randomly select an action say, Right. Logically it should move to 5th state but my above code 
uses the action 2 as the next state. so instead of going to 5th state it goes to 2nd state.

In the end my algorithm will work perfectly if the dimension of state and action matrices are same(m x m) but in my problem my state and action matrices are different (m x n). I tried to find a solution to this problem but failed to find an logical approach to find next state for $max(Q(s',a'))$ currently I am stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The comments in your code don't correspond to what you are actually doing. Try to avoid this always.)

You are conflating the transition and the reward matrices. For a non-stochastic environment, they should look something like this:

```
R <- matrix(c(
    -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, 10,
    -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, 10, -1, -1,
    10, 10, -1, -1),
    nrow=6, ncol=4, byrow=T)

T <- matrix(c(
    1, 2, 1, 4,
    1, 3, 2, 5,
    2, 3, 3, 6,
    4, 5, 1, 4,
    4, 6, 2, 5,
    6, 6, 3, 5),
    nrow=6, ncol=4, byrow=T)
```

The ε-greedy strategy would be:

```
greedy  <- function(s)    which(Q[s,] == max(Q[s,]))
egreedy <- function(s, e) if (runif(1, 0, 1) < e) greedy(s) else sample(1:ncol(Q), 1)
ca <- egreedy(cs, epsilon)
```

Then choosing the next state is just:

```
ns <- T[cs, ca]
```